# Is HttpAuthenticationMechanism distributable?

Tags: security, jakarta-ee, jaspic

I have e simple questions.

We have a JSF application with HttpAuthenticationMechanism.
Are Credentials distributable?
I mean if put in web.xml `<distributable/>` and deploy app on 2 nodes (wildfly) are credentials distributed from node to node?

Thanks in advance.